# How to create plain text links or string variables that is displayed as its value in the buffer?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

In my org-mode documents I want to be able to write:

```
#+VAR: that_year=2020
```

and then somewhere in text use it like:

```
"And [[var:that_year]] we are going to..."
```

which should be interpreted and displayed like a regular link description, so looking at it should just be:

```
"And 2020 we are going to.."
```

Then later on when changing `that_year=2020` to `that_year=2021` all occurences in the buffer of the variable link to `that_year` should also display 2021 instead of 2020.

Comment: does this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46043/11477) solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you!